# javascript context arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have the following code:

```
const person = {
  name: 'Bob',
  greet: () => {
    console.log(`Hi, my name is ${this.name}`);
  }
};

person.greet();
```

For some reason, it outputs:

```
Hi, my name is undefined
```

I'd expect it to output:

```
Hi, my name is Bob
```

Comment: Why did you expect that? The scope the arrow function binds isn't the object you're creating, `this` is whatever it was *where you're creating it*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An arrow function does not have its own this; the this value of the enclosing execution context is used

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Example:

```js
// An arrow function does not have its own this
// this of enclosing context is used
window.something = 'Yo yo yo'; 
const data = {
  something: 'Eduardo Stuart',
  
  arrowPrintName: () => {
    console.log(this.something) // this will print "window.something" instead
  },

  shortPrintName () {
    console.log(this.something) // this will print eduardo stuart
  }
}

data.arrowPrintName();
data.shortPrintName();
```